# How can I retrieve the data as of today in PHP PDO OOP?

Tags: php, vue.js, pdo, axios

I'm trying to display the data where match the date today. No data show in my page. I'm using PHP PDO with Axios. Can somebody help regarding my problem?

```
 public function retreiveDateToday() {
        $transaction_date = date("Y-m-d");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction WHERE datetime LIKE '%2019-05-19%'";

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([
            ":transaction_id" => $transaction_id,
            ":beneficiary_id" => $beneficiary_id,
            ":user_id" => $user_id,
            ":transaction_date" => $transaction_date
        ]);

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

VueJS Methods

```
 retrieveReturnMedicine : function() {
        axios({
            method : "GET",
            url : this.urlRoot + "gulod/retrieve_date_today.php"
        }).then(function (response){
            vm.dateToday = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

....

```
<?php

include '../../private/initialize.php';

$transaction = new Transaction();

echo json_encode($transaction->retreiveDateToday());
```

Comment: You first may check the server side working. After that you can check the Vue side.

Comment: No need to generate the date in PHP, it's easier to do that in SQL: `DATE(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE`